# Install multiple versions of Qt on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, qt, osx-mountain-lion

I would like to have multiple version of Qt installed on my Mac OS X (Mountain Lion) build server, as I need to build different applications against different versions of Qt. If I run a Qt installer, it seems to just overwrite whatever version was there before, with no option (that I can find) to install it anywhere else.

It is trivial to have multiple versions installed on other platforms (such as Windows and Linux), you can specify the path to which the Qt version will install.

Is there any way to achieve this on Mac OS X? Multiple installs of Mac OS X on the same machine is not a viable option for me (and Apple don't let you run virtual machines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build any Version of Qt on your own. This requires a compiler and a lots of time and cpu.. Have a look at the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/install-mac.html).
You then just have to put every version in another folder. To use another version just change the path in your environment settings.

P.S. It is recommended to exclude things like examples, demos etc. This will reduce the build process to a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

If you're installing using Qt Creator the default behaviour *should* be to install it into `/Users/(something)/Qt/Qt(version)`, you can then add the different version by going into `Preferences -> Build & Run -> Qt Version`. If you're getting different behaviour from the installer, or you're doing a non-Qt Creator related build then getting it from source and changing the install prefix when running `configure` works fine, that's how I do it in general.